# previous day's count except on Monday, use Friday's counts

Tags: sql-server, count, case, datepart

I have the below code. I am comparing counts from today's date to yesterday's date unless date falls on Monday then I want to use Friday's count.

```
select
cast(getdate() as date)run_dt,
'dx' as db,
'dbo' as [schema],
'tb_cust' as [table],
'completed status' as check_type,
a.curr_cnt,
a.prev_cnt,
abs(cast((a.prev_cnt - a.curr_cnt) / cast(a.curr_cnt as decimal(10,2)) as decimal(5,2))*100) as cal_prcnt_dff,
case 
when abs(cast((a.prev_cnt - a.curr_cnt) / cast(a.curr_cnt as decimal(10,2)) * 100  as int) ) >= 100
then 'Y'
else 'N'
end email_trigger,
concat('count on',' ', @curr_dt,' ','[',datename(dw,@curr_dt),']',' ' ,'increased/decreased by 100% from',' ',@prev_dt,' ','[',datename(dw,@prev_dt),']') as 'comment'
from (select 
      sum(
      case 
      when a.custstatus = 'completed'
      and a.custdate = cast(getdate() -1 as date)
      then 1
      else 0
      end) curr_cnt,
      sum(
      case 
      when a.custstatus = 'completed'
      and a.custtdate = cast(getdate() -2 as date)
     --and cast(getdate() as date) in ()
     --and datepart(dw,getdate()) in (3,4,5,6)
       --or 
      then 1
      else 0
      end) prev_cnt,

      a.custstatus
      from cte_apt a
      where 1=1
      and a.custstatus = 'completed'
      group by 
      a.custstatus)a
```

How can I get prev_cnt to count Friday when the day lands on a Monday?

```
  sum(
  case 
  when a.custstatus = 'completed'
  and a.custtdate = cast(getdate() -2 as date)
 --and cast(getdate() as date) in ()
 --and datepart(dw,getdate()) in (3,4,5,6)
   --or 
  then 1
  else 0
  end) prev_cnt,
```

Comment: Have you considered using `LEAD`/`LAG` and ensuring the weekend dates aren't in your data?

Comment: Also, get in the habit of using appropriate aslias. You alias your table `cte_apt` (which is a confusing name too, as it's not a CTE) as `a` and then alias the subquery itself as `a` as well. Also, why have `1=1` in the `WHERE`? When does `1` *not equal* `1`?